# What are the prerequisites for stochastic calculus?

Tags: stochastic-calculus

I am considering learning stochastic calculus myself, but do not have math background. Could you please suggest a list of books which will help to understand stochastic calculus?

Comment: I just think it is unrealistic to the extreme to attempt to learn stochastic calculus with no maths background.

Comment: what you mean "no math background"? Have you ever taken a graduate level probability course, for example? The one reference I can think of that introduces stochastic calculus as gently as possible is Lawrence Evans' "An Introduction to Stochastic Differential Equations", [here](http://ft-sipil.unila.ac.id/dbooks/AN%20INTRODUCTION%20TO%20STOCHASTIC%20DIFFERENTIAL%20EQUATIONS%20VERSION%201.2.pdf).

Comment: thanks for reply. i meant that i have no dyploma in maths. I've taken many different courses in statistics and probability, but seams it's not enough to undestand stochastic caculus. Maybe you can advise some additional books, which is better to read before start learning stochastic calculus.